# On a step in a proof in Hatcher

Tags: algebraic-topology

If $r:X\rightarrow A$ is a retraction, and $i:A\rightarrow X$ is inclusion, then $ri=1$. Hence, $r_*i_*=1$. (The stars indicate that they are the induced homomorphisms of the fundamental groups.) Why does this imply that $i_*$ is injective?

This comes from the proof of Prop 1.17 in Hatcher.

Answer (score 3):

Suppose $i_*(x)=i_*(y)$.  Then applying $r_*$ to both sides, we find $$x=r_*(i_*(x))=r_*(i_*(y))=y.$$

More generally, a similar argument shows that if $f$ and $g$ are functions such that the composition $fg$ is injective, then $g$ must be injective.